# Limits of lamp and mysql, performance?

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, limits

I'm running a linux-Server as a reseller.

The server some lamp-Setup and longtime load of 0.09
and maximum load of 0.31

- apache handles 130 domains (2 of them with 10,000 Pi's)
- mysql has 150 databases
- diskusage 20%
- memory 24G (8G free!)

Since two days we have database-problems (mysql-server is crashing).
The technicians said: well, you have some tables (max. 10) with large data: 8-14G

Can one confirm that these tables are my bottleneck?

that 14G-table-scheme is:

```
CREATE a_table (
  uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tstamp int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  crdate int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  cruser_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  deleted tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  hidden tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  pid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  item_uid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  item_table int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  c_ip tinytext NOT NULL,
  c_host text NOT NULL,
  c_ua text NOT NULL,
  c_language text NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  weekday int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `month` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hour` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `minute` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  views int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  clicks int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (uid),
  KEY parent (pid),
  KEY crdate (crdate),
  KEY views (views)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and has 65,000,000 entries

```
select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_ROWS * AVG_ROW_LENGTH  as SIZE
from information_schema.TABLES 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = "mytable" #comment line if need across databases
order by SIZE desc;
```

results:

```
TABLE_NAME  TABLE_SCHEMA    SIZE desc
tracker_log db208674_61 12712160967
cache_hash  db208674_61 1144536480
cache_pages db208674_61 828390864
```

Comment: Not without seeing the tables. You have 14G of data in one table? Are you sure the DB is normalized properly? Without the full schema I'm afraid there's probably not much anyone can do.

Comment: that 14G-table-scheme is:

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns in a table are not the only criteria to determine size, the number of rows in the table also are needed to get the complete size of the table.

Since you are using mysql, you can run the following query to get an approximate idea of how much space the tables are consuming (the size returned is in bytes), and take corrective actions accordingly on each of the table:

```
select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_ROWS * AVG_ROW_LENGTH  as SIZE
    from information_schema.TABLES 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA = "database_name" #comment line if need across databases
    order by SIZE desc;
```

Comment: My big question is: can one image that these conditions make the mysql crash?

Comment: @mxsteini possible, depending on how your mysql is configured. Try asking the question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ with updated details, like what are number of database connections, kind of disks used for hosting, mysql version, read/write slave configuration, and so on.

Comment: @mxsteini Were you able to resolve this? Don't forget to accept and upvote my answer if it helped :)